# Understanding binary search tree insertion using Python

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to understand following binary search tree node insertion implementation in Python. I have placed a few print statements within the insert function. I could understand the first two prints generated by two insert calls but I couldn't understand third print generated seems before 3rd insert call. The implementation with debug prints looks as follows:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


def insert(root, node):
    if root is None:
        root = node
        return root
    if node.value < root.value:
        root.left = insert(root.left, node)
        print("left: " + str(root.left.value))
    if node.value > root.value:
        root.right = insert(root.right, node)
        print("right: " + str(root.right.value))
    return root


root = Node(50)

insert(root, Node(10))
insert(root, Node(2))
insert(root, Node(80))
insert(root, Node(15))
insert(root, Node(60))
insert(root, Node(90))
```

The code prints:

```
left: 10
left: 2
left: 10
right: 80
right: 15
left: 10
left: 60

right: 80
right: 90
right: 80
```

My understanding so far:

1. `insert(root, Node(10))`

   (i) `__init__` with value = 10 called. Since root is already set to 50, program gets inside second if condition with 10<50.

   (ii) recursive insert function is called with root.left as None and node value as 10. Since root.left is None now, program gets in to first if condition and root gets value 10. This finishes the recursive call and program executes next statement which is `print("left: " + str(root.left.value))` this prints 10. Program evaluates third if condition as false as expected and finishes the function call for the insertion of 10.
2. `insert(root, Node(2))`

   (i) `__init__` with value=2 called. Program gets inside second if condition with 2<50.

   (ii) recursive insert function is called with root.left as 10 and node value as 2. Program again gets in to second if condition with 2<10.

   (iii) recursive insert function is called again with root.left as None and value as 2. Now program gets in to first if condition and root gets
   value 2. This finishes the recursive repeat calls and program executes next print statement `print("left: " + str(root.left.value))` which prints 2.

   (iv) Now as expected program evaluates third if condition as false and successfully calls return.
   But, before starting `insert(root, Node(80))`, it again goes back to print statement in second if condition and prints a 10.
   I did not get this, that why after finishing (or is it not?) the function call it is going back to the print statement again?

Comment: Not sure if you know this, but there is a site called pythontutor.com, go there and paste your code and see a step by step visualization of what's happening.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When node 2 is being inserted, it goes in the second if statement two times, as you've said:

```
insert(root, Node(2)) -> root being Node 50
insert(root, Node(2)) -> root being Node 10
```

So, when the recursive step ends, two print statements will run, but in the opposite order. This means that the first print will show Node 10's left (Node 2 that was inserted) and the second print will show Node 50's left (Node 10)

You can visualize the code above as a stack, so everything needs to be executed before the algorithm finishes and what is in the top will be executed first.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a few experiments and based on the outcomes, following is an answer:

Additional prints are getting executed for the nodes which are injected 2 or more level deeper as the insert function's `return root` is going via intermediate nodes to the root. Posting the code with additional debug prints for tracking ids of root objects and time stamp of print executions.

**Code:**

```
import time


class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


def insert(root, node):
    if root is None:
        root = node
        return root
    if node.value < root.value:
        root.left = insert(root.left, node)
        print("left: " + str(root.left.value) + "  " + str(time.clock()))
    if node.value > root.value:
        root.right = insert(root.right, node)
        print("right: " + str(root.right.value) + "  " + str(time.clock()))
    print(id(root))
    return root


root = Node(50)
print("root node id: " + str(id(root)))

insert(root, Node(10))
insert(root, Node(2))
insert(root, Node(80))
insert(root, Node(15))
insert(root, Node(60))
insert(root, Node(90))
```

**Program output with inline comments:**

root node 50 was assigned object id 50359600

```
 root node id: 50359600
```

First node 10 inserted

```
left: 10  3.77580764525532e-07
```

With the `return root` call insert function returns root 50 residing at 50359600

```
50359600
```

Second node 2 inserted

```
left: 2  3.398226880729788e-05
```

With the `return root` call insert function returns to the 50359600 but via 50360272 (id of 2's immediate root 10) and prints 10 before returning root 50 @ 50359600

```
50360272
left: 10  4.8330337859268096e-05
50359600
```

80 is a right side node immediately after 50 on the right hand side, so `return root` directly reaches 50@50359600 after injecting 80.

```
right: 80  6.305598767576385e-05
50359600
```

Similar to node 2 in earlier execution, after inserting 15 insert function has to return to 50 with `return root` call via 10.

```
right: 15  7.702647596320853e-05
50360272
left: 10  8.986422195707663e-05
50359600
```

Likewise....

```
left: 60  0.00010345712947999577
50360304
right: 80  0.0001155397139448128
50359600

right: 90  0.00012837745993868089
50360304
right: 80  0.00014008246363897238
50359600
```